# Creation of Tag file so it can be used for STL classes

Tags: vim

Using vim 7.3.1, ubuntu 11.10

I am creating a tag file using ctags while in the directory where I am running it from I have a link to /usr/include/c++/4.6.1/ where my stl headers are installed...  I am creating the tags file like this:

```
ctags -R *
```

Although  I am able to jump to the definition of the std namespace (using CTRL }) the same does not happen when I try the same for any other stl class like string vector etc

Any ideas how I can go around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by adding the following in my .bashrc:

```
alias maketags='ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --language-force=c++  /usr/include/c++/4.6.1/ /usr/include '
```